# How to use the Django ORM to query only by date in a datetimefield

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a table with a DataTimeField.  I'd like to get a list of all the objects where the DateTimeField = a specific day (ignoring the time part).

The SQL would look something like:

```
select * from tblname where date(start)='2011-01-14'
```

Is it possible to get the ORM to do this kind of query?

I can do a start__range(...) kind of query, but I was wondering if I could do it the other way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [QuerySet API reference](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#year):

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2005)
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__month=12)
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__day=6)
```

This works for Dates and DateTimes.

Answer (score 2):

```
MyModel.object.filter(start__year=2011, start__month=01, start__day=14)
```

the problem with this query is that if your DB dont suport index with functions (Hello MySQL) you have an inneficient query.

One alternative can be that you add a new field `start_date = models.DateField(...)` and overload your `save(...)` method to set the field correctly, or if you are more a database side dev, use a trigger for the same function, after this, you can do:

```
MyModel.object.filter(start_date=date(2011, 1, 13))
```

Comment: I think you mean single equals sign in your first code example.